# Как правильно просчитать?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой самописный слайдер, нужно что бы слайды всегда были на весь экран, независимо от изменения размера экрана, не могу придумать, как так сделать

Проблема в том, что при изменении ширины экрана слайдер сбивается и приходит в правильное состояние, только после прогона всех слайдов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить данную проблему? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdgGqr

```js
var pervSliderButton = document.querySelector('.js-slider__button_perv');
var nextSliderButton = document.querySelector('.js-slider__button_next');

pervSliderButton.addEventListener('click', sliderPerv);
nextSliderButton.addEventListener('click', sliderNext);



window.addEventListener('resize', resizeSlide);
function resizeSlide() {
 console.log(document.body.clientWidth);
 var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper__slide');
 for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
 slides[i].style.width = document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
 sliderWrap = document.querySelector('.slider__wrapper');
 sliderWrap.style.width = slides.length * document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
 return document.body.clientWidth;
}

sliderPoint = 0;
function sliderNext() {
 var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper__slide');
 sliderWrap = document.querySelector('.slider__wrapper');
 if (sliderPoint <= (-(slides.length-1)*resizeSlide())) {
  sliderPoint = 0;
  sliderWrap.style.transform = 'translateX('+ sliderPoint +'px' + ')';
 } else {
  sliderWrap.style.transform = 'translateX('+ (sliderPoint - resizeSlide()) +'px' + ')';
  sliderPoint = sliderPoint - resizeSlide();
 }
}

function sliderPerv() {
 var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper__slide');
 sliderWrap = document.querySelector('.slider__wrapper');
 if (sliderPoint >= 0) {
  sliderPoint = -(slides.length-1)*resizeSlide();
  sliderWrap.style.transform = 'translateX('+ sliderPoint +'px' + ')';
 } else {
  sliderWrap.style.transform = 'translateX('+ (sliderPoint + resizeSlide()) +'px' + ')';
  sliderPoint = sliderPoint + resizeSlide();
 }
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 max-height: 500px;
}

.slider__wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 position: relative;
 width: 7680px;
}

.wrapper__slide img {
 width: 100%;
}

.wrapper__button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 8%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
 transition: 0.1s;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper__button:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}

.slider__button_perv {
 left: 0;
}

.slider__button_next {
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__wrapper">
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874100_1383101_25792ac067.jpg" alt="Слайд 1">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874104_1822794_cefef52967.jpg" alt="Слайд 2">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874108_2174295_2a76b9d678.jpg" alt="Слайд 3">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874123_9925860_740e80c1e2.jpg" alt="Слайд 4">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slider-position">
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper__button slider__button_perv js-slider__button_perv"></div>
  <div class="wrapper__button slider__button_next js-slider__button_next"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Введение

Чтобы растянуть блок на всю высоту и ширину экрана необходимо родительскому элементу присвоить:

```
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

И растянуть картинку на всю высоту:

```
.wrapper__slide img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

### Финальный вариант

```js
var pervSliderButton = document.querySelector('.js-slider__button_perv');
var nextSliderButton = document.querySelector('.js-slider__button_next');

pervSliderButton.addEventListener('click', sliderPerv);
nextSliderButton.addEventListener('click', sliderNext);



window.addEventListener('resize', resizeSlide);
function resizeSlide() {
 console.log(document.body.clientWidth);
 var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper__slide');
 for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
 slides[i].style.width = document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
 sliderWrap = document.querySelector('.slider__wrapper');
 sliderWrap.style.width = slides.length * document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
 return document.body.clientWidth;
}

sliderPoint = 0;
function sliderNext() {
 var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper__slide');
 sliderWrap = document.querySelector('.slider__wrapper');
 if (sliderPoint <= (-(slides.length-1)*resizeSlide())) {
  sliderPoint = 0;
  sliderWrap.style.transform = 'translateX('+ sliderPoint +'px' + ')';
 } else {
  sliderWrap.style.transform = 'translateX('+ (sliderPoint - resizeSlide()) +'px' + ')';
  sliderPoint = sliderPoint - resizeSlide();
 }
}

function sliderPerv() {
 var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper__slide');
 sliderWrap = document.querySelector('.slider__wrapper');
 if (sliderPoint >= 0) {
  sliderPoint = -(slides.length-1)*resizeSlide();
  sliderWrap.style.transform = 'translateX('+ sliderPoint +'px' + ')';
 } else {
  sliderWrap.style.transform = 'translateX('+ (sliderPoint + resizeSlide()) +'px' + ')';
  sliderPoint = sliderPoint + resizeSlide();
 }
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.wrapper__slide img {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.slider__wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 position: relative;
 width: 7680px;
}

.wrapper__slide img {
 width: 100%;
}

.wrapper__button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 8%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
 transition: 0.1s;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper__button:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}

.slider__button_perv {
 left: 0;
}

.slider__button_next {
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__wrapper">
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874100_1383101_25792ac067.jpg" alt="Слайд 1">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874104_1822794_cefef52967.jpg" alt="Слайд 2">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874108_2174295_2a76b9d678.jpg" alt="Слайд 3">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874123_9925860_740e80c1e2.jpg" alt="Слайд 4">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slider-position">
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper__button slider__button_perv js-slider__button_perv"></div>
  <div class="wrapper__button slider__button_next js-slider__button_next"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

ps. На соседний вопрос уже ответил. Может быть там что-нибудь полезное найдешь.

Comment: Это не решило проблему, в итоге все равно когда меняешь размер экрана, появляется баг

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi а пример можно? на больших экранах изображение не на весь экран с отступом снизу?